# How can I retrieve all rows from a JSON array that match a specific country ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named TEST_TABLE in my MySQL database. This table contains a column called COUNTRIES_IDS, which has a data type of json. I used a json array because MySQL does not support multiple foreign keys on the same column. However, I am not sure if this is the most optimal approach, and if there is a better alternative.

Currently, there are `1,348,193` rows in this table.

**Here is how the table looks:**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    COUNTRIES_IDS JSON NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = UTF8_UNICODE_CI;
```

**Here is the data that is inside the table:**

| ID | COUNTRIES_IDS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32] |
| 2 | [39, 30, 6] |
| 3 | [20, 38, 35, 13, 32, 31, 2, 47, 46, 24, 1, 5, 9] |
| 4 | [7] |
| 5 | [14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20] |
| Etc to 1,348,193 rows | Etc to 1,348,193 rows |

**The expected output of the query should be like this:**

| ID | COUNTRIES_IDS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32] |
| 5 | [14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20] |
| ... | ... |

**My requirements are as follows:**

1. How can I fetch all the rows that contain country ID 15?
2. How can I optimize the query to retrieve results faster without having to read all 1,348,193 rows, as this would significantly slow down the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    countries_ids JSON NULL,
-- create an index which will improve searching queries
    INDEX idx_countries_ids ((CAST(countries_ids AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)))
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = UTF8_UNICODE_CI;


INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '[41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32]'),
(2, '[39, 30, 6]'),
(3, '[20, 38, 35, 13, 32, 31, 2, 47, 46, 24, 1, 5, 9]'),
(4, '[7]'),
(5, '[14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20]');
```

```
SELECT id, CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR)
FROM test
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(countries_ids, '[15]')
```

| id | CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32] |
| 5 | [14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20] |

```
SELECT id, CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR)
FROM test
WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(countries_ids, '[15]')
```

| id | CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32] |
| 5 | [14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20] |

```
SELECT id, CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR)
FROM test
WHERE 15 MEMBER OF (countries_ids)
```

| id | CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [41, 9, 38, 15, 22, 5, 7, 32] |
| 5 | [14, 22, 15, 30, 36, 20] |

```
EXPLAIN   -- an example which shows that the index is used in the query execution
SELECT id, CAST(countries_ids AS CHAR)
FROM test
WHERE 15 MEMBER OF (countries_ids)
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | test | *null* | ref | idx_countries_ids | idx_countries_ids | 9 | const | 2 | 100.00 | Using where |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/reJ8fBEG)

See: [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), [Multi-Valued Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued)

Comment: I am currently using MySQL version 5.7. Can you confirm if everything is still working as expected? Additionally, could you provide a more detailed explanation about Multi-Valued Indexes, as I am having trouble understanding them?

Comment: @TahaSami In 5.7 you can use only JSON_CONTAINS(). Neither another shown functions nor multivalued indices are supported on this version. https://dbfiddle.uk/n7TBcXeE And the only way to improve on 5.7 is data normalising (not JSON but separate id-country_id pairs with according indexing).

Comment: Are you referring to Multi-Valued Indexes, which are not supported in MySQL 5.7? Additionally, I am having trouble understanding your solution mentioned at the end of your comment. Could you please modify your answer to be applicable for MySQL version 5.7?

Comment: @TahaSami *Additionally, I am having trouble understanding your solution mentioned at the end of your comment.* You must study Normal forms. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization